# How do I do a "word count" command in Windows Command Prompt

Tags: windows, command, prompt

I know the command in Unix/Linux systems is "wc" but that doesn't work in Windows.

For reference the description for the UNIX word count command wc is:

> Print newline, word, and byte counts for each FILE, and a total line
> if more than one FILE is specified. With no FILE, or when FILE is -,
> read standard input.

Answer (score 4):

The closest I know of is the PowerShell equivalent [Measure-Object.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx)

```
Get-Content filename.txt | Measure-Object -Word
```

Should give a word count similar to:

```
wc -w filename.txt
```

If you look at the help for Get-Content you will see it has aliases of gc, cat, and type and the alias for Measure-Object is measure so you could also type:

```
cat [filename] | measure -w
```

Comment: There are more examples in a later Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59685819/count-the-number-of-characters-words-and-lines-in-powershell

Answer (score 3):

`find` command could be used in windows cmd to find line count (with the `/c` switch), word count etc.

http://rickardnobel.se/counting-lines-in-windows-command-prompt/

Answer (score 3):

"Find" will be able to do the task similar to word count as RRM told.

**Eg.**

Query user | find /v /c ""

/v – Show any lines that don’t contain the string of words you specified.
/c - Count the number of lines that matches the word in fine.

**Query user | find /i "active" /c**

/i - Ignore case
/c - Count the number of lines that matches the word in fine.

Comment: Please add correct tags for your question, like `bash` etc.

Comment: In this example is it looking for the word "active"? If I look for count of "fail" in "result.txt": Query user | find /i "fail" /c E:\tests\result.txt

Comment: wc - print newline, word, and byte counts for each file. It doesn't look for occurrences of a specific word.

Answer (score 0):

wc is part of the [GNU Core Utils for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm). I often install [GnuWin32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuWin32) utilities on Microsoft Windows systems to supply equivalents to the commands I use regularly on Linux and OS X systems.

Comment: Awesome! I assume there's a version for 64 bit systems?