# R - How to execute PowerShell cmds with system() or system2()

Tags: r, powershell, cmd, operating-system

I working in R (on a Windows OS) attempting to count the number of words in the text file without loading the file into memory. The idea is to get some stats on the file size, line count, word count, etc. A call to R's system() function that uses `find` for the line count is not hard to come by:
[How do I do a "word count" command in Windows Command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29177443/how-do-i-do-a-word-count-command-in-windows-command-prompt)

```
lineCount <- system(paste0('find /c /v "" ', path), intern = T)
```

The command that I'm trying to work with for the word count is a PowerShell command: `Measure-Object`. I can get the following code to run without throwing an error but it returns an incorrect count.

```
print(system2("Measure-Object", args = c('count_words.txt', '-Word')))
[1] 127
```

The file, `count_words.txt` has on the order of millions of words. I also tested it on a .txt file with far fewer words.

```
"There are seven words in this file."
```

But the count again is returned as 127.

```
print(system2("Measure-Object", args = c('seven_words.txt', '-Word')))
[1] 127
```

Does `system2()` recognize PowerShell commands? What is the correct syntax for a call to the function when using `Measure-Object`? Why is it returning the same value regardless of actual word count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### The issues -- overview

So, you have two issues going on here:

1. You aren't telling `system2()` to use powershell
2. You aren't using the right powershell syntax

#### The solution

```
command <- "Get-Content C:/Users/User/Documents/test1.txt | Measure-Object -Word"
system2("powershell", args = command)
```

where you replace `C:/Users/User/Documents/test2.txt` with whatever the path to your file is. I created two .txt files, one with the text "There are seven words in this file." and the other with the text "But there are eight words in this file." I then ran the following in R:

```
command <- "Get-Content C:/Users/User/Documents/test1.txt | Measure-Object -Word"
system2("powershell", args = command)

Lines                             Words Characters          Property           
-----                             ----- ----------          --------           
                                      7                                        


command <- "Get-Content C:/Users/User/Documents/test2.txt | Measure-Object -Word"
system2("powershell", args = command)

Lines                             Words Characters          Property           
-----                             ----- ----------          --------           
                                      8
```

#### More explanation

From `help("system2")`:

> system2 invokes the OS command specified by command.

One main issue is that `Measure-Object` isn't a system command -- it's a PowerShell command. The system command for PowerShell is `powershell`, which is what you need to invoke.

Then, further, you didn't quite have the right PowerShell syntax. If you take a look at [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-6), you'll see the PowerShell command you really want is

```
Get-Content C:/Users/User/Documents/count_words.txt | Measure-Object -Word
```

(check out example three on the linked documentation).