# Count the number of characters, words and lines in PowerShell

Tags: linux, powershell, wc

In Linux we have the "wc" command which allows us to count the number of characters, words and lines in a file.

But do we have a similar cmdlet in PowerShell. The Measure-Object cmdlet I tried could only count the number of lines but not the characters and words.

Comment: the `Measure-Object` cmdlet CAN count lines, words, and chars. please add your code to the Question so we can see what needs changing.

Comment: It works. Unfortunately, `Measure-Object` seems to be much slower than `wc`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
Get-Content [FILENAME] | Measure-Object -Character
```

It counts the number of characters in the file.

```
Get-Content [FILENAME] | Measure-Object -Word
```

It counts the number of words in the file.

```
Get-Content [FILENAME] | Measure-Object -Line
```

It counts the number of lines in the file.

Comment: Also just `cat [filename] | measure -w -c -l` using the built-in aliases.

Answer (score 4):

Measure-Object do exactly that.
You do have to specify the parameters you want measured for the characters, words and lines to be returned.

> **Example 3: Measure text in a text file**
>
> This command displays the number of characters, words, and lines in
> the Text.txt file. Without the Raw parameter, Get-Content outputs the
> file as an array of lines.
>
> The first command uses Set-Content to add some default text to a file.
>
> ```
> "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" | Set-Content -Path C:\Temp\tmp.txt
> Get-Content C:\Temp\tmp.txt | Measure-Object -Character -Line -Word
>
> Lines Words Characters Property
> ----- ----- ---------- --------
>     4     4         15
> ```

Reference: [Microsoft.Powershell.Utility/measure-object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/measure-object?view=powershell-7)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to count all words in all text files in a directory:

```
Get-ChildItem <INPUT_FOLDER_PATH> -Recurse -Filter *.txt | Get-Content | measure -Word -Line - Character
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
type '.\filename.txt' | Measure-Object -Line -Word -Character
```

Gets you everything.  type takes far less time to type for text based files.